# ZK Charts, clearing the chart

Tags: charts, zk

I am using ZK charts in my project. I am having line type charts. And using addSeries on my chats. But when I want refresh charts as in when user if fetching new Data, I am not sure how to clear the graph. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you are using series to add points on the chart (in my example I am using Float values) you can empty data displayed by setting an empty list to the series, like this:

```
chart.getSeries().setData(new ArrayList<Float>());
```

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me,
just write this line before populating your chart

```
chart.getSeries().setData(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that just call the method

```
chart.invalidate();
```